# Kendo grid - strange problem with displaying toolbar

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, razor-pages

I've got some strange problems with the kendo Grid.
I recorded a very short video to show you what is exactly happening:
[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh1Ih.gif)

Grid code:

```
<div class="demo-section k-content wide">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Usage)
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Country);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Users);
        })
        .Scrollable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5)
        )
    )
</div>
```

This grid is placed in a Partial View, and the funniest thing is that if I will paste this code to normal View, the toolbar is displaying good

#Edit

My goal is 3 Partial Views -> 1 with kendo Chart, 2 with another kendo Chart and 3 with this kendo Grid.
I pasted all to first partial and the same to second partial. In first everything is displaying fine:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyA9W.png)

But when I will switch to the second partial, my charts are narrower and problem this grid appears:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnOEc.png)

To display these Partial I'm using Bootstrap nav:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="columnChart-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#columnChart" role="tab" aria-controls="columnn" aria-selected="true">Partial 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="lineChart-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#lineChart" role="tab" aria-controls="line" aria-selected="false">Partial 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="columnChart" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="columnChart-tab">
        <partial name="~/Pages/Shared/_ColumnChart.cshtml" model="Model" />
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="lineChart" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="lineChart-tab">
        <partial name="~/Pages/Shared/_LineChart.cshtml" model="Model" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When I will set second tab default as active, I have problem with the first one then

Comment: That is weird....... have you tried clearing cache? or runningi it in another browser? I would guess its something wrong with the outer div

Comment: I cleared cache, tried with Opera and Mozilla - still the same

Comment: make sure that the grid has a unique name.  Kendo controls apply classes for styling using jquery id matching on the grid.

Comment: Names are different, I know that jquery create id based on control names. Problem is with bootstrap nav I think, but no have idea how can I resolve this